# Indexeddb open('table1', 2) not working

Tags: indexeddb

so the code is as below:

```
var request = indexedDB.open("content", 1);
request.onsuccess = function(e) { console.log("onsuccess"); } // got onsuccess
```

and when I do

```
var request = indexedDB.open("content", 2);
request.onsuccess = function(e) { console.log("onsuccess"); } // got nothing
```

why when as I increase the version number, the onsuccess is not fired? And what should i do to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an open connection which is preventing the upgrade attempt from proceeding.

A "versionchange" event will be fired at any open connections that are blocking the upgrade. The connections can be closed in response.

A "blocked" event will be fired at the request that is blocked if it is not immediately unblocked by the other connections closing.

See: https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#handling-versionchange